# How can I charge just one Lithium Polymer cell?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, balancing, lithium-polymer

I have a small 3.7V 100mAh [Lithium polymer battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery). This is just like any other Li-Pol battery, but it is smaller.

Like any rechargeable battery, I want to recharge it. From what I found online, I see this technology needs a different process to recharge than usual, but there are products that do it for me and I just need to plug cables.

Now the problems begin. I searched in online stores, like eBay and [every product](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=lithium%20polymer%20Balance%20Chargers&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.XLithium%20polymer%20Balance%20&_nkw=Lithium%20polymer%20Balance%20&_sacat=0) says **2S** or more (this means 2 cells). Maybe this is good for people that have big Li-Pol battery, but not for my purposes.

So, can I just recharge my one battery with one of these? Will doing so cause problems? Or if it need 2 cells, well, I use two of then in parallel (or in series) and do it. This is not the best solution...

Can someone recommend a good charger for just one cell or the proper method for charging multiple battery cells?

Comment: http://ch00ftech.com/2013/10/08/light-up-earrings/4/ lengthy discussion of and example circuits for charging a tiny 20mAh lipo cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Search on Amazon.com for "lipo charger"](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=lipo%20charger&url=search-alias=aps). There are several options that will charge a single cell (1-4 cells, 1-6, etc.). [Click here for one example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001BEXDRQ).

Just be aware that many R/C-oriented chargers do not include a power supply, as they're intended to be hooked up to lead-acid batteries when out and about. (The linked item does not need an external supply.)

Comment: Lol, sometimes ask to people is better than ask to google! This TLP-2000 really work for me. Now that I know it exist, I find more models.